# Find coverage of a set of intervals

Tags: algorithm, intervals

I came across this question while preparing for an interview long back and thought it was an interesting problem to solve. The problem is this:
Find the coverage of a set of intervals
For example - given [1,4), [-2,3), [9,10) : the output should be 7 (the set of intervals cover -2,-1,0,1,2,3,9).

My initial approach was to iterate over the set of intervals; add the number in each interval to a Sorted Linked list. If any number already exists in the sorted list, skip it. I believe this takes O(N^2) time and consumes O(N) space, so we could probably do better.

Alternately, we could use an [Interval BST](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0QOYtSsTg4). However, that seems to be primarily used for finding out if there is an overlap with a given interval (which takes O(lgn)). Finding the coverage of it would seem to take O(n^2) again. Can we do better than O(n^2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at them as pairs and sort them by the first element.

After sorting you'll have : {<-2, 2>, <1,3>, <9, 9>}.

Sorting will take O(NlogN).

Now make a variable sum = 0.

Then set L = (1).left and R = (1).right.

Linearly traverse everything keeping the largest R you've encountered until R < (k).left, then do sum += abs(L - R) + 1 and proceed for the rest as just described. This will take about O(N). So, altogether : O(NlogN + N) ~ O(NlogN).

The space is also linear.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;
typedef pair<int, int> pii;

int main() {
    int l, r;
    vector<pii> pairs;
    while (cin >> l >> r) {
        pairs.emplace_back(l, r);
    }
    pairs.emplace_back(INT_MAX, INT_MAX); // sentinel
    sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), 
    [](const pii& x, const pii& y) { return x.first < y.first; });

    auto p_one = pairs.begin(), p_two = pairs.begin() + 1;
    int L = p_one->first;
    int R = p_one->second;
    int sum = 0;
    while (p_two != pairs.end()) {
        if (R < p_two->first) {
            sum += abs(L - R) + 1;
            L = p_two->first;
            R = INT_MIN;
        }
        p_one++; p_two++;
        if (p_one->second > R) R = p_one->second;
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```

P.S. I haven't fully tested the code, but it seems to work.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes it will execute, did you even test the code? do you see that I add a sentinel? http://ideone.com/wCVAWJ

Comment: @j_random_hacker keep in mind that these aren't rectangles, these are intervals, so when you do input, your L is always less than or equal to R. Also rectangles can't have negative parameters.

Comment: I missed the sentinel.  Not sure why you're asking me to keep in mind that these aren't rectangles -- they aren't a lot of things, should I keep them all in mind?

Comment: @j_random_hacker my initial solution had that 'active rectangle's width', as you call it, added at the end, but then I decided to add a sentinel, without a sentinel the code would look extremely messy, consider how many if's you'd have to write after the loop : 1) test if (n-1).right < (n).left, then add abs((n).left - (n).right) + 1; 2) if not then add abs(L - R) + 1; 3) maybe some other if that I missed. I think having a sentinel is much easier.